# What is the Key to Time, and how powerful is it?

Tags: doctor-who

I just recently heard about this item from Doctor Who, but I haven't watched the episodes involving this item yet. So I would like to know what the Key to Time does, and how powerful it is?

Comment: http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Key_to_Time

Comment: Do you have a specific question about the powers of the Key to Time, or are you asking for a general summary a la the wikia link?

Comment: How powerful is it? About twelve. Twelve powerful.

Comment: First, you need to know about the [white guardian](https://youtu.be/4lCrV4s7Avc). And, of course **beware the *black guardian***.

Answer (score 1):

As its first power, the key to time stops time. Once assembled, time stops in the universe, all at once.  The Doctor attempts to complete the key with a duplicate piece of the sixth part - it only works to a degree - the universe is trapped in a time loop several seconds long, gradually lengthening as the artificial sixth piece degraded.

After assembly, the person in possession of the Key has access to godlike powers in the manipulation of time and space.

The Doctor was asked to collect the pieces of the Key to Time so the Guardian could use it to correct certain inconsistencies in the fabric of spacetime that could only be done in the stopped state provided by the key.

It was the center of the first season long arc done on Doctor Who during the Tom Baker era.  A long-form story structure was attempted with the thread of the blue crystal from Metebelis III, but this was much more complete and structured - every story of the season waqs centered around the collection and assembly of the Key.